# How to get cost/reward current estimation for all arms using Vowpal Wabbit with Python

Tags: reinforcement-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am starting to work with *Vowpal Wabbit* with Python and I am kinda struggling with its lack of documentation.

Do you guys know what modeling it uses as a cost/reward estimation for each arm? Do you know how to retrieve this  current estimation?

```
 vw = pyvw.vw("--cb_explore 2 --epsilon 0.2")
  input = "2:-20:0.5 |  Anna" 
  vw.learn(initial_input)
  input = "1:-10:0.1 | Anna"
  vw.learn(initial_input)
  vw.predict(" | Anna")
```

**Output would be:**

```
[0.10000000149011612, 0.9000000357627869]
```

How can I also get the expected value for each arm? Something like

```
[-10.00, -20.00]
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `_explore` you get back a PMF over the given actions. This is true for CB and CB_adf.

However, when using the non-explore version for each of those things differ a bit.
`--cb` is going to give you the chosen action directly, whereas `--cb_adf` is going to return the score for each given action.

So in this situation changing to using action dependent features (ADF) should provide the score/estimated cost.